# Nuxt: Generate 404 pages for different languages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a multilingual (English/French) website created in Nuxt. I am able to create a different 404 page for two different languages while in development mode, but as soon as I generate static pages for my website Nuxt only generates a single 404 HTML page for the English version.

I was able to force it to generate the French version on `fr/404.html`, but Nuxt won't send the errors to this path. Is there a way to create multiple 404 pages in Nuxt? What would be the approach for that?

I am not attaching any code, because I'm more interested in a general way for doing this, and not for a specific solution for my code. :)

Thanks a lot,